# Ignore Files in Subversion on Per-Project Basis

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I recently began working on a large project that contains a huge number of files.  For some reason (which I don't understand), the team decided **not** to use svn:ignore and, as such, each developer needs to provide his or her own set of ignore parameters.

I'm using the TortoiseSVN client, and there is a way to do this (using the global ignore property), except it would then apply across ALL other projects that I have checked out which I don't want.

Is there any way to ignore files on a per-project basis without using the svn:ignore parameter?  Thanks for any help.

**Edit**: I wanted to specify that svn:ignore is not an option.  The solution would have to be something locally.

Comment: I assume that the right click->TortoiseSVN->Add to ignore list...
does simply svn:ignore parameter right? because This would solve the problem.

Comment: @bua - Yes, "Add to ignore list..." just uses the svn:ignore parameter.

Comment: I'm just guessing- maybe You could rename Your files, folders to hidden ones locally... (.[name]). Then svn would not find them.

Comment: Renaming the folder would not take care of the problem, since Windows doesn't consider .folder to be hidden like linux does.  TortoiseSVN will still "see" it.

Comment: So you come questioning how to do X in tool Y, with the pre-requisite that Z, which is the way to do X in Y is not an option. What do you expect except people pointing out to you that Z is the way to do X in Y? `svn:ignore` _is_ the tool to ignore project-specific files and if your team decided it wants to do without, then it is left without the means to ignore project-specific files. That's just the way this world was made.

Comment: @sbi - I actually agree with you.  I know svn:ignore is the right solution.  But, in this case, I was not part of that decision making, so I have to try to find a workaround.  That's what this question is about.  (However, I think I have managed to convince the group why they want to use svn:ignore, so, that makes this question null and void.)

Comment: @Jason: See, this is why pointing out an option is good even when they are explicitly excluded in the question. `:)` I'm glad you could convince the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the ignore list.  You can read about it in the [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html).

This does set the `svn:ignore property` for the path, but you can apply it recursively if needed.

Since the properties are actually saved in the repository, the other developers would not need to set their own ignore lists.  They will automatically get the same properties when they next update their working copies.

Comment: Jason can not use svn:ignore list !

Comment: The OP originally stated that it was not desirable due to the misunderstanding that each developer would have to set up their own list.  I was simply pointing out that this is not the case, since the properties are actually stored in the repository itself.

Comment: Accepting because this *is* the (true) correct solution.  As sbi pointed out above, there's not always an alternative solution when a good solution is already in place.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN can recursively set the `svn:ignore` property for an entire directory subtree.  So if your repository is organized in a way that each project has its own folder, you can apply a different `svn:ignore` pattern for each project.

Check the "Apply property recursively" box when setting the value.